# Creating a table layout with column depends on spinner in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, tablelayout

I want to create a table that the columns'text depends on spinner. Later to add the row, i can color the specified cell. It looks like this : http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2j639xf&s=8#.U-mRRpD-Lcs
That example is landscape because i develop it on dekstop, so i want a table like that as portait in android.

The problem is : 
 1. when i run it on device, the spinner is gone
 2. I don't know yet how to color each cell in the table. Or should I make a new question?

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reservation_schedule);
    Spinner spinnerFacility = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerFacility);

    ArrayList<String> alTop = getTimeTableColumnTop((int)spinnerFacility.getSelectedItemId());
    String[] column = alTop.toArray(new String[alTop.size()]);
    ArrayList<String> alLeft = getTimeTableColumnLeft();
    String[] row = alLeft.toArray(new String[alLeft.size()]);
      int rl=row.length+1; int cl=column.length+1;

       Log.d("--", "R-Lenght--"+rl+"   "+"C-Lenght--"+cl);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
       TableLayout tableLayout = createTableLayout(row, column,rl, cl);
       HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

       hsv.addView(tableLayout);
    sv.addView(hsv);
    setContentView(sv);
}

private ArrayList<String> getTimeTableColumnTop(int facilitySelectedIndex)
{
    ArrayList<String> timeTableColumnTop = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(facilitySelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        timeTableColumnTop.add("Discuss Room 1");
        timeTableColumnTop.add("Discuss Room 2");
        timeTableColumnTop.add("Discuss Room 3");
    }else
    {
        timeTableColumnTop.add("Pri-View 1");
        timeTableColumnTop.add("Pri-View 2");
        timeTableColumnTop.add("Pri-View 3");
        timeTableColumnTop.add("Pri-View 4");
        timeTableColumnTop.add("Pri-View 5");
    }
    return timeTableColumnTop;
}

private ArrayList<String> getTimeTableColumnLeft()
{
    ArrayList<String> timeTableColumnLeft = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 8 ; i<17; i++)
    {
        timeTableColumnLeft.add(i+":00");
    }
    return timeTableColumnLeft;
}
```

For the function createTableLayout(row,column,rl,cl); i use the code from http://www.prandroid.com/2014/05/creating-table-layout-dynamically-in.html

The activity_reservation_schedule.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/reservation_spinner_facility_prompt"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerFacility"
    android:prompt="@string/reservation_spinner_facility_prompt"
    android:entries="@array/reservation_facility_entries"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">ReservationTab(Schedule)</string>
<string name="reservation_spinner_facility_prompt">Pick a facility</string>
<string-array name="reservation_facility_entries">
  <item>Discussion Room</item>
  <item>Private Viewing</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Note : i'm new on Android, i'm using eclipse. This is my first post here, please excuse my english. Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points:

If i understood you correctly,

- You need to "add" the scroll view to your root view linearlayout.
- Add a Custom Item Selected listener for Spinner and change layout depending on selection

e.g

Sample Code:

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
    Spinner spinnerFacility = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerFacility);
    spinnerFacility.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    // more of your code.....
    ll.addView(sv)  // instead of setContentView(sv)
```

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

```
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
            "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ll.removeView(sv);


        ArrayList<String> alTop = getTimeTableColumnTop(pos);
        String[] column = alTop.toArray(new String[alTop.size()]);
        ArrayList<String> alLeft = getTimeTableColumnLeft();
        String[] row = alLeft.toArray(new String[alLeft.size()]);
          int rl=row.length+1; int cl=column.length+1;

           Log.d("--", "R-Lenght--"+rl+"   "+"C-Lenght--"+cl);

         sv = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
           TableLayout tableLayout = createTableLayout(row, column,rl, cl);
           HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(getApplicationContext());

           hsv.addView(tableLayout);
        sv.addView(hsv);
        ll.addView(sv);

      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Maddy. I just realize that the code is setViewContent, not addView. It looks like setViewContent replace the LinearLayout, which is where the spinner is.

Comment: Anyway in onCreate, I need to add 'sv = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());' before 'll.addView(sv);'